# LESS variable file not global

Tags: css, sass, webpack, less

I use less-loader with webpack, the annoying part is I have to import the variable.less in every single of my module's less file. Why it can't be just global?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question (can't tell if the problem you're having is something about your webpack setup), but if you're saying you have to do

**variables.less**

```
@var1: value1;
@var2: value2;
```

**module1.less**

```
@import 'variables';
selectorA {
    propertyX: @var1
}
```

**module2.less**

```
@import 'variables';
selectorB {
    propertyY: @var2
}
```

you can approach it like this:

**all.less** (other common names for this are `main.less` and `app.less`)

```
@import 'variables';
@import 'module1';
@import 'module2';
```

**variables.less**

```
@var1: value1;
@var2: value2;
```

**module1.less**

```
selectorA {
    propertyX: @var1
}
```

**module2.less**

```
selectorB {
    propertyY: @var2
}
```