# Less loader in vue-cli project

Tags: vue.js, webpack

I am trying to use a less file in my vue-cli created project.

Also the question if this is best practice. Earlier I added webpack globally and started a watcher and added a webpack.config.js

This time I created the project with vue-cli / vue ui and the doc says I have to use a vue.config.js where I do this:

```
module.exports = {
css: {
    loaderOptions: {
        // pass options to sass-loader
        less: {
            // @/ is an alias to src/
            // so this assumes you have a file named `src/variables.scss`
            data: `@import "@/all.less";`
        }
    }
}
}
```

I added the file in src/all.less and also tried src/assets/less/all.less and changed the path in the config file. Both do not seem to work tho.

Comment: The object value of `loaderOptions.less` should be actual options for `less-loader`. `sass-loader` has a `data` option, but `less-loader` does not, so you can't do that. If you're trying to set globals, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617057/less-variable-file-not-global.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using vue cli 3 . just use less right in your vue file, just set the lang to "less" or "scss" - pretty handy. There should be no additional configuration on the webpack side :

```
<style lang="less">
```

@import './less/index.less';